# Cube map/ frame buffer problems

Tags: dictionary, opengl, cube

So... I am trying to filter an environment map for a BRDF shader, as explained here: https://learnopengl.com/PBR/IBL/Specular-IBL. However, I can't get my filtered result to be properly stored (when loaded, I get a black texture full of artifacts.)

I figure it must have something to do with the frame buffer, since glCheckFramebufferStatus() keeps returning 0 on the LOD/sides loop, but I have spent a couple hours trying to understand why... and I can't see the problem. glGetError() returns 0, I made sure to generate the frame buffer/ render/ buffer before the loop starts, and at that point everything seemed complete. The rest of the program runs fine, and there were no errors compiling the shader I am using.

I am quite new to openGL, is there something obvious I am missing? I am assuming the problem must be in this section... but does it look like it should work? Could it be something I did wrong elsewhere?

This is the code:

```
if (cubeMapGenerated == false){
    //Frame Buffer:
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &frameBuffer);
    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &renderBuffer);
    glGenTextures(1, &genCubeMap);

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBuffer);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, genCubeMap);

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
    {glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + i, 0, GL_RGBA16F, 128, 128, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, nullptr);}
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE); //params
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP); //generate mipmaps

    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, renderBuffer);
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, width_, height_);
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, renderBuffer);

    if(glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
       std::cout << "Framebuffer is not complete at gen. Staus: " << glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) << std::endl;

    GLuint projection_location, view_location, model_location, normal_matrix_location,
        specular_map_location, roughness_location;

    cubeMapGen_program_->bind(); //bind irradiance sahder
    projection_location = cubeMapGen_program_->uniformLocation("projection");
    view_location = cubeMapGen_program_->uniformLocation("view");
    model_location = cubeMapGen_program_->uniformLocation("model");
    normal_matrix_location = cubeMapGen_program_->uniformLocation("normal_matrix");
    specular_map_location = cubeMapGen_program_->uniformLocation("specular_map");
    roughness_location =brdf_program_->uniformLocation("roughness");

    glUniformMatrix4fv(projection_location, 1, GL_FALSE, e_captureProjection.data());
    glUniformMatrix4fv(model_location, 1, GL_FALSE, model.data());
    glUniformMatrix3fv(normal_matrix_location, 1, GL_FALSE, normal.data());

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, specular_map_);
    glUniform1i(specular_map_location, 0);

    for (unsigned int mip = 0; mip < maxMipLevels; ++mip){//render each mip
        // resize framebuffer according to mip-level size.
        unsigned int mipWidth  = 128 * std::pow(0.5, mip);
        unsigned int mipHeight = 128 * std::pow(0.5, mip);
        glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, mipWidth, mipHeight);
        std::cout << "width: " << mipWidth << " height: " << mipHeight << std::endl;

        glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, renderBuffer);
        glViewport(0, 0, mipWidth, mipHeight);

        float mproughness = (float) mip / (float)(maxMipLevels - 1);
        glUniform1f (roughness_location, mproughness);

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)//render each side
        {
            glUniformMatrix4fv(view_location, 1, GL_FALSE, e_captureViews[i].data());
            glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + i, genCubeMap, mip);

            if(i == 0 && glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
            {std::cout << "ERROR::FRAMEBUFFER:: Framebuffer is not complete! Map: " << mip << std::endl;}

            glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
            glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
            glVertex3f(2, -2, -2); glVertex3f(2, -2, 2); glVertex3f(2, 2, 2); //Right
            glVertex3f(2, -2, -2); glVertex3f(2, 2, 2); glVertex3f(2, 2, -2);
            glVertex3f(-2, -2, -2); glVertex3f(-2, 2, 2); glVertex3f(-2, -2, 2); //Left
            glVertex3f(-2, -2, -2); glVertex3f(-2, 2, -2); glVertex3f(-2, 2, 2);
            glVertex3f(-2, -2, 2); glVertex3f(-2, 2, 2); glVertex3f(2, 2, 2); //Front
            glVertex3f(-2, -2, 2); glVertex3f(2, 2, 2); glVertex3f(2, -2, 2);
            glVertex3f(-2, -2, -2); glVertex3f(2, 2, -2); glVertex3f(-2, 2, -2); //Back
            glVertex3f(-2, -2, -2); glVertex3f(2, -2, -2); glVertex3f(2, 2, -2);
            glVertex3f(-2, 2, -2); glVertex3f(2, 2, -2); glVertex3f(2, 2, 2);   //Top
            glVertex3f(-2, 2, -2); glVertex3f(2, 2, 2); glVertex3f(-2, 2, 2);
            glVertex3f(-2, -2, -2); glVertex3f(2, -2, 2); glVertex3f(2, -2, -2); //Bottom
            glVertex3f(-2, -2, -2); glVertex3f(-2, -2, 2); glVertex3f(2, -2, 2);
        }
    //std::cout << glGetError() << ", " << glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout<<"New pre filtered map generated"<<std::endl;
    cubeMapGenerated = true;
    }//cubemapgen
    glEnd();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to read about [Vertex Specification](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification) and to use the state of the art way of [Vertex Array Objects](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object) for drawing.

But, if you draw the objects in to deprecated [Fixed Function Pipeline](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fixed_Function_Pipeline) style, then geometric objects are drawn by enclosing a series of vertex coordinates between [`glBegin`/`glEnd`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glBegin.xml) pairs.

You have to finish the drawing sequence by `glEnd`, before you can change or manipulate the framebuffer.

Move the `glEnd` instruction in the inner loop and your code should work

```
for (unsigned int mip = 0; mip < maxMipLevels; ++mip)
{

    .....

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)//render each side
    {
         glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + i, genCubeMap, mip);

         glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
         glVertex3f(2, -2, -2); glVertex3f(2, -2, 2); glVertex3f(2, 2, 2);

         .....

         glVertex3f(-2, -2, -2); glVertex3f(-2, -2, 2); glVertex3f(2, -2, 2);
         glEnd(); // <---- "end" the draw sequence 
    }
}
```

See [OpenGL 3.0 API Specification; 2.6.3 GL Commands within Begin/End; page 24](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec30.pdf)
or [OpenGL 4.6 API Compatibility Profile Specification; 10.7.5 Commands Allowed Between Begin and End; page 433](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.compatibility.pdf):

> The only GL commands that are allowed within any Begin/End pairs are the commands for specifying vertex coordinates, vertex colors, normal coordinates, texture coordinates, generic vertex attributes, and fog coordinates ...

Comment: Yes, that was it. Thank you!